# Python Pandas make new Series using other field

Tags: python, pandas

I am a freshman in Python and Python Pandas.

This is my dataframe

```
         date                      open      high       low     close    volume  
       0 2020-09-02 12:55:00+00:00  0.038904  0.038940  0.038833  0.038840  1233.725
       1 2020-09-02 13:00:00+00:00  0.038838  0.038940  0.038741  0.038873  1637.552
       2 2020-09-02 13:05:00+00:00  0.038866  0.038988  0.038862  0.038980  1196.561
       3 2020-09-02 13:10:00+00:00  0.038985  0.039022  0.038919  0.039017  1527.921
       4 2020-09-02 13:15:00+00:00  0.039020  0.039200  0.039000  0.039101  3741.821
```

How can make new column

I wish make like this

up = max(close - close.shift(1), 0)

Thanks you in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) instead subtract shifted values and then [`Series.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) for convert negative values to `0`:

```
df['new'] = df.close.diff().clip(lower=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast advice. I will check soon :)

Comment: Awesome! Working well. Thanks a lot.